# how to allow users from a specific country using django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to only allow user from specific country say USA. I think it ca be implemented as follows:-

```
def redirect_based_on_ip(request):
    ip = request.meta['REMOTE_ADDR']
    if ip == SOMETHING:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/something')
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/something_else')
```

Can is simply insert USA in place of SOMETHING or i need some code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `iprestrict` package. Find the below link 
[click here](https://django-iprestrict.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)